# iPad 1 not receiving motion updates but iPad 2 does

Tags: ios, ipad, ipad-2, gyroscope

I'm doing what I thought was the standard approach for reading the device's angle:

```
motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
if (!motionManager.deviceMotionAvailable)
    return NO;
[motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdates];
```

And then later:

```
CMDeviceMotion *deviceMotion = [motionManager deviceMotion];
if (deviceMotion) {
    CMAttitude *attitude = deviceMotion.attitude;
    if (attitude) {
        // yay
    }
}
```

This code works fine on the iPad 2 but not on the iPad 1.

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

iPad 1 doesn't have a gyro. It was introduced in 2. That might have something to do with it. :)

Comment: Not relevant, because iPad 1 still detects device orientation.

Comment: @ShowFly: No bebraw is right. An accelerometer has no chance to detect the device orientation, it only tells you the direction of gravity. Imagine a steering wheel like rotation which is an device orientation change but does not change the gravity vector at all. Thus an attitude makes no sense. See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMAttitude_Class/Reference/Reference.html